# Can't access bundle from pod library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, bundle

I try to use `PEPhotoCropLibrary` in my project. I added it using cocoapods installer. But when I try to use it in my code, I get error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: ' -[NSBundle initWithURL:]: nil
>   URL argument'

That happens here:

```
NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PEPhotoCropEditor" withExtension:@"bundle"];
```

Then I tried to get access to `PEPhotoCropEditor.bundle` in my code:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "PEPhotoCropEditor", withExtension: "bundle")
```

and got `nil` as result. Project structure is here:
[image]

What is wrong here, why I can't access library bundle?

Comment: what does NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PEPhotoCropEditor" withExtension:@"bundle"]; ?

Comment: That code from PEPhotoCropEditor library.

Comment: is this your library : https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor

Comment: Yes, this library i'm trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Please change:

```
NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PEPhotoCropEditor" withExtension:@"bundle"];
```

to:

```
NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] URLForResource:@"PEPhotoCropEditor" withExtension:@"bundle"];
```